# Does DeWALT Precision Wrench™ eliminate the need for a torque wrench?

Tags: torque

My [DeWALT impact wrench DCF923B](https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools/impact-drivers-and-wrenches/atomic-20v-max-38-in-cordless-impact-wrench-with-hog-ring-anvil-tool-only/dcf923b) has a feature called Precision Wrench™. This is defined elsewhere as, *"In Forward, the tool will pause before impacting to help prevent overtightening. In Reverse, the tool lowers speed when fastener is loose to help prevent run-off."*

To make this useful do I need to know the max-torque of the gun before it impacts? Will this be useful for a mechanical/automotive job that requires between 32 lb/f - 85 lb/f. Can I simply rely on Precision Wrench™, and not use a torque wrench?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this particular impact, no ... you'd still need to use a torque wrench. In most cases it is advised you don't even use an impact for tightening a nut or bolt. Even with ones which have torque limiting abilities, it is still recommended you go back and verify with a torque wrench (ie: Milwaukee M18 FUEL 1/2" drive -  https://youtu.be/tozbCF02Hsg).